# VBA Excel ListBox Control Selection Event Changes View

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have an ActiveEx listbox control in my workbook and, when a user clicks on one of the items in the listbox the view is automatically updated such that the top of the listbox becomes the topmost visible row in the sheet. This effect is undesirable and also seems strange. I've searched and searched and can find no references to such behaviour. Does anybody know what causes this or how it can be avoided?

Comment: can you post the vba code?

Comment: Try an `Activecell.Activate` after the click event to reset the view to the active cell. Not sure this is what you are looking for, but it works.